# How to implement a N seconds timer using time(NULL) and while loop instead of sleep(N)?

Tags: c, time, timer, sleep

for example, if I want to implement a timer which executes codes per second, I can use sleep(1):

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main(){
    while(1){
        printf("%ld\n",time(NULL));
        fflush(stdout);
        sleep(1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But the total time elapsed of sleep(1) and other codes may be over 1 second actually, so I use while loop instead:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main(){
    time_t t=0;
    while(1){
        if(t!=time(NULL)){
            t=time(NULL);
            printf("%ld\n",t);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

but the problem is, in this program the codes in loop executes per second, how about if I want to execute the codes per N (e.g.:3,4...) seconds?

I tried it but not works:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main(){
    time_t t=0;
    while(1){
        if((t-time(NULL))%3==0){
            t=time(NULL);
            printf("%ld\n",t);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

it executes codes in loop multiple times until the second that %3==0 is passed.

How should I modify it? Or in other words, what is the general solution to implement timers using this method for N seconds?

Comment: Sounds to me like you actually need a event library. Check out [libevent](http://www.libevent.org), or [libev](http://libev.schmorp.de/).

Comment: Even if you get your method to work, it's no better than using `sleep`. A process that spins in an infinite loop can still be suspended by the OS to allow other processes to run.

Comment: What is your problem with Sleep()?  Note that there are a lot of clueless people spreading FUD about such calls.  You are almost certainly trying to fix a problem that does not exist.  How accurate do you need your interval?

Answer (score 1):

Just trying to fix your code, you can do it like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    time_t previousTime = time(NULL);
    time_t interval = 3;
    time_t currentTime;

    while(1)
    {
        if((time(&currentTime) - previousTime) >= interval)
        {
            printf("%ld\n", currentTime);
            previousTime += interval;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

You can change `interval` as desired. Now, this doesn't assure you that at exactly `interval` seconds `printf` will execute due to other factors. What this assures you though is that each execution of `printf` will never drift as time passes.

Remember, doing a proper interval timer is more involved than this simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to create a thread which should write some data to a pipe for every one second.

Clearly the work of the thread is to just add some date to pipe for every one second. So use while loop to add data for second.

Use can use sleep(1) or use any looping techniques to calculate the time.

In the main function, put the read call (for reading the pipe) in a while loop.

If something is read to the pipe, which means one second was completed. and then inside the while loop you can add the code for your task.
Once your task is completed then the process will wait until it reads from the pipe.

You can change the timer in the thread as you need, which can be used as N seconds timer.

As the time is completed your task will start in the main.

I guess this technique can be helpful.